# Comparing date using cakephp from text file

Tags: sql, date, cakephp

I have this warning and in my database only the date time in and id insert

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1048: Column 'employee_id' cannot be null [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 684]
```

and I want to save the date as the date time in and out according to the condition that if the the id holding the time will compare the date and if the larger time will be its date the time in and the other one will be the date time out.I'm using text file like this

```
No  TMNo    EnNo    Name    GMNo    Mode    DateTime
0   1   1       1   30  2013-11-25 08:00:00
1   1   1       1   30  2013-11-25 17:00:00
2   1   27      1   30  2013-11-25 09:02:34
3   1   27      1   30  2013-11-25 18:04:10
4   1   28      1   30  2013-11-25 10:02:34
5   1   28      1   30  2013-11-25 13:04:10
```

and I upload this in the program.Thank you I hope can help me.

```
 function logs()
    {   

    App::import('Helper', 'Time');
    $time = new TimeHelper();

    /***Start Read Text File***/
    if(!empty($this->data)){
        $file = fopen($this->data['BiometricLog']['log_file']['tmp_name'], "r");
        $members = array();

        while (!feof($file)) {
           $members[] = fgets($file);
        }

        fclose($file);
        foreach($members as $indexKey=>$value){
            $line_string = preg_replace('/\t/', '||', $value);
            $column_string = explode("||", $line_string);
            //debug($column_string);
            if($indexKey > 0){
                $data_needed['Employee']['employee_id'] =  (isset($column_string['2']))?preg_replace('/(\0|\r\n|\r|\n)+/', '', $column_string['2']):'';
                $data_needed['Employee']['datetime_in'] =  (isset($column_string['6']))?preg_replace('/(\0|\r\n|\r|\n)+/', '', $column_string['6']):'';
                $DateTime_in = $data_needed['Employee']['datetime_in'];
               //set time string into numeric
                $DateTime_in=strtotime($DateTime_in);

                $employee_pid = $data_needed['Employee']['employee_id'];

                $DateTime_in_1='';

                $DateTime_out='';

                //GET THE DATE ONLY
                 for ($i=0; $i<11; $i++){
                        $DateTime_in_1 = $DateTime_in_1.''.$DateTime_in[$i];

                    if($employee_pid == $employee_pid[$i]){

                          if(strtotime($DateTime_in) > strtotime($DateTime_in[$i])){

                            $DateTime_out = $DateTime_in_1.''.$DateTime_in[$i];

                          }
                    }



        }

                debug( $DateTime_out);

                $this->loadModel('BiometricLog');
                $this->BiometricLog->create();
                if($this->BiometricLog->save($data_needed['Employee'])){

                }else{
                    debug("Not Save");
                }

                /*$this->BiometricLog->save($this->$data_needed['Employee']);
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));*/
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: what is the content of $data_needed['Employee']? debug($data_needed['Employee'])

Comment: app\controllers\biometric_logs_controller.php (line 468) 1

Comment: well that means there is nothing to save... you have a problem building the data to be saved.

Comment: Can you tell me where I got wrong in building this.I don't have any idea.

Comment: also why do you have this here  for ($i=0; $i<11; $i++){ and instead of 11 count($data_needed['Employee']['employee_id']).
Would be smarter if you save the user ID and then based on that you will start updating the database with in and out datetimes and at the end you make calculations. At least this is how (i think) I will do it

Comment: You should also have a look here for start and end timings:
http://si1.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score 1):

first check what you have here:

```
$employee_pid = $data_needed['Employee']['employee_id'];
debug($employee_pid);die;
```

I think your line here:

```
$data_needed['Employee']['employee_id'] =  (isset($column_string['2']))?preg_replace('/(\0|\r\n|\r|\n)+/', '', $column_string['2']):'';
```

You probably don't have a $column_string['2'] and it goes to : ''. Try for testing purposes to change the '' with '999' to see if it works OK, like this

```
$data_needed['Employee']['employee_id'] =  (isset($column_string['2']))?preg_replace('/(\0|\r\n|\r|\n)+/', '', $column_string['2']):'999';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
if($this->BiometricLog->save($data_needed['Employee'])){
```

with this:

```
if($this->BiometricLog->save(
    array(
        $this->BiometricLog->alias => $data_needed['Employee']
    )
)){
```

Comment: It is the same.Nothing change.Thank you.I hope for another answer.